# Change in AppSettings needs restart my Application how can I avoid?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, appsettings, configurationmanager

I'm using C# .NET 2.0 Windows Application.

and I'm using app.config for my Application Settings.

but change in AppSettings doesn't reflected runtime, it Needs Application to be restarted.

How can I avoid it.

Here is my code snippet I used to read and write the Application Settings.

I'm reading the Setting like this

```
string temp = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key);
```

I'm updating the value like this where node is the current configuration/appSettings Node

```
node.Attributes["value"].Value = value;
xmlDoc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try calling

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings")
```

to refresh the AppSettings section of the file from disk. Once they have been refreshed, you should be able to read the new values.

I've just tested this and it does indeed work.

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't seem to refresh the value retrieved via ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySetting"].

Comment: Where do you include this?

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could create a singleton 'Options' to hold on to your application settings and perform your read/writes for you.  Once loaded, changing the .config doesn't require reloading, you simply set a property on the singleton and call your .Save() method.

The 'runtime' version of your settings is in the singleton, no need to read from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use ConfigurationManager to read settings, instead use:

```
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile).AppSettings.Settings["value"];
```

Comment: Yes this can also possible, but it's probably not the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: here you use ConfigurationManager too.

Answer (score 1):

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

works!!

But be careful that if we are in debug mode, the configuration file can be called ***xxxxx.vshost.exe.config***, where *xxxxx* is your project name.